# Detect changes with JavaScript on dom element/watermark

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I am using a watermark, absolute positioned, displaying over multiple child elements.
Can any changes to this watermark be detected such as removal from the dom, and style changes including opacity/display/visibility when applied with the devtools?

I have tried using mutationobserver, but this only works for changes made programmatically to the element.
Tried it with setInterval as well, but once the element is removed from the dom, it doesn't detect it either.

Any insight or simply pointings in the right direction would be truly appreciated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When using mutationobserver and use any event which makes changes to the element it detects those changes, but when doing it from within the devtools it doesn't recognise those modifications.

Comment: There’s no way to deal with everything a user might try. An interval that checks for an element’s existence can be removed or the interval function replaced. If you need an indelible watermark use an image or file with it already embedded. (Which can also be removed, but separate conversion.)

Comment: Not to mention a proxy can alter your js/html/etc on the way in anyway, or greasemonkey etc

Comment: Also, a MutationObserver will still fire if the DOM is updated via devtools, you just need to ensure you're observing the correct element in the structure, and also are using the relevant `options` in your `config` object you provide to `observe()`

Comment: What happens if a user disables JS? Are they free to change/remove the watermark or does the whole application stop working?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I had it set up as follow: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k20uLby8/), where it only detects when bind to the click event.

Comment: @Reyno, not going to worry about disabling JS, there will always be ways, just want to reduce those ways.

Comment: Try IntersectionObserver trackVisibility, [info](https://web.dev/articles/intersectionobserver-v2#what_does_the_new_code_look_like_in_practice).